# Is there any mechanism to auto squeeze in Matlab / Octave

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

For an nD array, it would be nice to be able to auto squeeze to remove singleton dimensions. Is there a way to do this that I don't know about? This would be especially useful for aggregate functions (e.g. sum, mean, etc) where you always expect a result with fewer dimensions.

Here's a simple example:

```
>> A = ones(3,3,3);
>> B = mean(A);
>> size(B)
ans =  
   1   3   3

>> squeeze(B)
ans =
   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   1   1   1
```

It would be nice if Matlab/Octave would automatically do the squeezing for me. Or if there was a way to turn that option on (something similar to `hold on` for plots).

Comment: Are you referring to the display of the matrices, or to the matrices themselves? I’d find it scary if dimensions arbitrarily disappeared from a matrix, it would make writing algorithm logic really hard.

Comment: Also, should `a=[1,2,3]` return a column vector then? Do the same thing as `a=[1;2;3]`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Your second question is already answered, I think, by the need to be compatible with `squeeze`'s behaviour: row vectors are _not_ squeezed into columns

Comment: Problem is, singleton dimensions are used extensively for vectorization of code. If you find a solution that would make matlab always automatically do that, it would also do it for its own code, which often relies on those singletons existing (e.g. for broadcasting). You may just break many of the MATLAB inbuilts.

Comment: When i have the memory to spare i use a lot of n-dimensional projection and broadcasting to speed up code. Automatic squeezing would break all of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Matlab does *not* have that. And I don't think it would be a good idea. Consider a modified version of your example:

```
>> A = ones(3,1,1,3);
>> B = mean(A);
>> size(B)
ans =
     1     1     1     3
```

What should "auto-squeeze" do here? Reduce `B` to size `[1 1 3]` or to `[1 3]`?

- You could argue that it should remove the *same* dimension that `mean` has turned into a singleton. But then it would have to be done *within* the `mean` function, perhaps with an optional input argument. Once you get the function output, there is no information *how* it was obtained.
- Or you could argue that it should remove *all* singleton dimensions, like `squeeze` (more or less) does. But then it would remove dimensions that were already singleton in the function *input*, which is probably unwanted.

If you ask me, having a *second* input in `squeeze` specifiyng which (singleton) dimensions to remove would be a nice addition (in the same vein as you can use `mean(A, 1)` to force the operation to be applied along the first dimension even if `A` happens to be a row vector).

Comment: Agreed. You can use `permute` to remove a specific singleton dimension.

Comment: For me, I would prefer to remove all singleton dimensions. I'm not even sure I like singletons in the first two dimensions. But I digress. The easiest to _implement_ would be to remove _all_ singleton dimensions. But some users might prefer a behavior to remove only the dimension that just went to one. Syntax could be `auto reduce on all` or `auto reduce on` to handle both of these cases, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Luis and Cris, but I would add the following.

Both Matlab and Octave **do** automatically squeeze extra dimensions, in a very particular scenario: any dimensions *at the end* that have been reduced to singletons, are automatically squeezed out.

E.g.

```
A = ones([1,2,3,4]);
B = mean(A, 4);
size(B)
% ans = 1   2   3
```

Note, how the answer is `[1,2,3]`, and *not* `[1,2,3,1]`. This is in contrast to languages like python, for instance, where a size of (1,1) is very different to a size of `(1,)`.

Therefore, with regard to your questions, one way to use this to your advantage could be to ensure that the dimension that is to be reduced is always found at the end, and thus automatically simplified.

This becomes even more useful when you realise that:

```
size(A(:))       % ans =   24    1     (i.e. 24)
size(A(:,:))     % ans =    1   24
size(A(:,:,:))   % ans =    1    2   12
size(A(:,:,:,:)) % ans =    1    2    3    4
```

Meaning, if you order your dimensions hierarchically you can ensure that any operations that need to take place over the higher dimensions, can a) be vectorised easily, and b) give a natural result, without the need to waste time squeezing or permuting the resulting dimensions.

Comment: Matlab does that too. The "official" view to look at it, however, is the other way around (which is of course equivalent): [any array can be considered to have infinitely many trailing singletons](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/521706-why-does-size-x-100-return-1)

Comment: Thanks, nice catch, I didn't mean that to sound that it was an octave only point.

Comment: Well, I am not sure it does, `size(B,34)` returns `1` :). But I see your point.