# Matlab "auto-squeeze" plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Matlab plot requires the data to be of the same dimension. Meaning, you cannot plot a 1x10 vector with a 1x1x10 vector. This is sometimes necessary. For those purposes, you can use the *squeeze* function to get rid of the singleton dimensions.

However, this is kind of a hassle. For the *plot function specifically*, it would be useful to have the argument always *squeezed*. How would one go about creating a new function, lets call it *splot* which squeezes every input and passes it onto *plot*. Here is an attempt (that doesn't work)

```
function  splot(varargin)

    for i=1:length(varargin)
        varargin{i}=squeeze(varargin{i});
    end

plot(varargin)

end
```

*plot(varargin)* part fails, because that is simply not how matlab syntax works. But is there any way to achieve what I want? I guess I could write a long *if elseif* chain where I manually write the case with every possible number of input arguments like:

```
if length(varargin)==2
    plot(varargin{1},varargin{2})
if length(varargin)==3
    plot(varargin{1},varargin{2},varargin{3})
```

But this is going to be very annoying. Any better ideas.

This question is similar to [Is there any mechanism to auto squeeze in Matlab / Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65205007/is-there-any-mechanism-to-auto-squeeze-in-matlab-octave) , however, not similar enough, because the other question is for squeezing every vector, which is a bad idea. Here I am asking a way to squeeze only the inputs to the plot function and requiring syntax help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) there are several ways to call `plot`. Generally

- Just numeric arrays, these can be on their own, or one or more pairs

  `plot(Y)`, `plot(X,Y)` or `plot(X1,Y1,...,Xn,Yn)`
- Numeric arrays as before, with a char array giving the line spec

  `plot(X,Y,LineSpec)` or `plot(Y,LineSpec)`
- Either of the previous two, plus name-value pair options

  `plot(___,Name,Value)`

In any of these cases, you want to squeeze the first `N` inputs which are numeric, since either of the optional additions have the first non-plottable input as a char.

We can achieve that with the following code, see the comments for details:

```
function h = splot( varargin )
    % Check if there are any optional inputs, which will either be 
    % LineSpec (which is a char) or name-value pairs (which the
    % first of will be a char)
    bNumericArg = cellfun( @isnumeric, varargin );
    % By default, assume all inputs are arrays to plot
    lastArrayArg = numel(varargin);
    if ~all(bNumericArg)     
        % In this case, there are some optional inputs, get last array index
        lastArrayArg = find( ~bNumericArg, 1 ) - 1;
    end
    % Squeeze the arrays
    for ii = 1:lastArrayArg
        varargin{ii} = squeeze(varargin{ii});            
    end
    % Plot with all inputs, optional output
    if nargout > 0
        h = plot( varargin{:} );
    else
        plot( varargin{:} );
    end
end
```

There are two possible cases I've not handled here which the `plot` function can handle,

- Having the first input as the target axes i.e. `plot(ax,___)`, could be achieved by altering the loop slightly to start from 1 or 2 depending if the first input is an axes object
- Having pairs of arrays each with their own line spec argument i.e. `plot(X1,Y1,LineSpec1,...,Xn,Yn,LineSpecn)`. The later pairs will be ignored. This would be trickier to handle since you'd likely have to parse all inputs and check whether a char is just a line spec or if you're messing with name-value pairs. Maybe a heuristic to do with "two arrays then a char, repeated". I've never used this syntax so omitting the over-complication for now.